# "Slippery Slope" - a Parametric Trajectory problem

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis, mathematical-physics, parametric

I'm designing some equipment that spits out a small ball, which I want to capture when it lands, without it bouncing away.  I figure this can be done by having the ball strike a slope tangentially.  I define the problem as:

"A particle P subject to earth's gravity leaves a launch point (0,k) at positive velocity V in both the x and y direction.  Is there a slope S, lying below and to the right of k, such that for any V, the particle hits S tangentially ?  If so, express Sy as a function of Sx"

[Diagram shows x and y axes (black), Particle P's initial velocity vectors (red), and subsequent parabolic motion (blue, depending on V).  Curve S (green) is formed when P glances tangentially regardless of V.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9jOf.jpg)

Forming the parametric equations for Px and Py as functions of t (time) is simple.  Px and Py can then be expressed as functions of V.  Conceptually, the constraint that the slope of S equals the slope of P at the point of impact should be incorporated as a constraint, but not sure how to do this.

Appreciate all assistance

Comment: Does "any $V$" mean the vectors that have the same length as $V$ but different directions? Because I think adjusting the length (speed) of the initial vector makes it impossible to have a common curve S ...

Comment: Another question: Why can we assume that there is a commons curve (slope) S for the different trajectories? The range of a thrown ball, for example (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trajectory#Range_and_height), does depend on the initial angle ...

Comment: All initial velocity vectors V have the same initial direction (45 degrees), just different magnitudes.  The trajectory of P for each V will differ and have a different slope at the impact point with S.  The question asks whether S, which is the curve formed by all such impact points, exists.